# Hash table C implementation - Separate Chaining

Tags: performance, c, hash-map

I've written a C implementation of a hashmap of strings including the basic operations and a strategy for handling hash collisons.

Additionally, I've included some tests, specifically for cases involving hash collisions which, I confess, gave me a bit of trouble initially.

Thank you in advance for your time :)

ps, if you prefer to view on github: https://github.com/JosephSBoyle/HashMap

> hashmap.h

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "hashmap.c"

/* Create a hashmap.*/
Node** hm_create(void);

/* Add an item to the hashmap */
void hm_add(Node** hmap, char key[], char value[]);

/* Remove an item from the hashmap */
void hm_del(Node** hmap, char key[]);

/** Get an item from the hashmap 
 * @returns the value corresponding to 'key' or the terminating character '\0'
 * if no such item exists. */
char* hm_get(Node** hmap, char key[]);
```

> hashmap.c

```
#define BUCKETS 1000000
#define PRIME_SEED_1 17
#define PRIME_SEED_2 97
#define KEY_CHARS 128
#define VALUE_CHARS 128
#define NODE_SIZE sizeof(Node)

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* A key-value node in a single-linked list. */
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    Node* next;
    char key[KEY_CHARS];
    char value[VALUE_CHARS]; 
};


Node* create_sentinel_node(){
    void* ptr = malloc(NODE_SIZE);
    if (ptr == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        Node* node = (Node*)ptr; // safely typecast the pointer
        node->next = NULL;
        strcpy(node->key, "\0");
        strcpy(node->value, "\0");
        return node;
    }
}


size_t modular_hash(char* string) {
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (char* character=string; *character != '\0'; character++) {
        hash += ((int)*character + PRIME_SEED_1) * PRIME_SEED_2; 
    }
    return hash;
}


Node** hm_create(void){
    static Node* keys[BUCKETS] = {};
    for (size_t i=0; i<BUCKETS; i++){
        keys[i] = create_sentinel_node();
    }
    return keys;
}

void hm_add(Node** hmap, char key[], char value[]){
    Node* node = hmap[modular_hash(key)];

    if (strcmp(node->value, "\0") == 0){
        // there's no item in this bucket.
        strcpy(node->key, key);
        strcpy(node->value, value);
        return;
    }

    while(true){
        if (strcmp(node->key, key) == 0){
            // the key already exists as a node in the linked list
            // so we can simply replace the value.
            strcpy(node->value, value);
            return;
        }
        if (node->next == NULL){
            // no more nodes, append a new node to the linked list.
            void* ptr = malloc(NODE_SIZE);
            if (ptr == NULL){
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } 
            Node* new_node = (Node*)ptr; // safely typecast the pointer
            new_node->next = NULL;
            strcpy(node->value, value);
            strcpy(new_node->key, key);
            node->next = new_node;
            return;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void hm_del(Node** hmap, char key[]){
    size_t khash = modular_hash(key);
    Node* node = hmap[khash];
    
    void* prev_node = NULL;
    Node* head = node;
    
    // find the node
    while (strcmp(head->key, key) != 0){
        if (head->next == NULL){
            // the key doesn't exist in this hashmap.
            return;
        }
        head = head->next;
        prev_node = head;
    }

    // are we deleting the first node?
    if (prev_node == NULL){
        // are we deleting the only node?
        if (head->next == NULL){
            // reset the node to the sentinel node.
            strcpy(node->value, "\0");
            strcpy(node->key, "\0");
        } else {
            // we are deleting the first of n>1 nodes.
            hmap[khash] = head->next;
        }
    } else {
        // there must be a previous node.
        Node* prev_node = (Node*)prev_node;

        // is this the last node?
        if (head->next == NULL){
            prev_node->next = NULL;
        } else {
            // we are deleting neither the first nor the last node.
            prev_node->next = head->next;
        }
        free(head);            
    }

}

char* hm_get(Node** hmap, char key[]){
    Node* node = hmap[modular_hash(key)];

    // skip list elements in the bucket (linked list) that don't match our key.
    while (strcmp(node->key, key) != 0){
        if (node->next==NULL){
            return "\0";
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    return node->value;
}
```

> tests.c

````
#include "hashmap.h"

/** TESTS
 * These tests test the collision handling of the hashmap.
 * NOTE: To cause collisions, replace the return value of the hash function with a constant int, e.g `return 0;`
 */
void main(){

    // test adding and getting an item
    Node** hm0 = hm_create();
    hm_add(hm0, "bob", "x");
    
    char* a = hm_get(hm0, "bob");
    assert(strcmp(a, "x") == 0);
    
    // test deleting an item that doesn't exist
    Node** hm1 = hm_create();
    hm_del(hm1, "bob");
    
    char* b = hm_get(hm1, "bob");
    assert(strcmp(b, "\0") == 0);

    // test getting a deleted item
    Node** hm2 = hm_create();
    hm_add(hm0, "bob", "the dog");
    hm_del(hm2, "bob");
    
    char* c = hm_get(hm2, "bob");
    assert(strcmp(c, "\0") == 0);

    // test overwriting a value
    Node** hm3 = hm_create();
    hm_add(hm3, "bob", "foo");
    hm_add(hm3, "bob", "bar");
    
    char* d = hm_get(hm3, "bob");
    assert(strcmp(d, "bar") == 0);
    
    // test deleting the last item
    Node** hm4 = hm_create();
    hm_add(hm4, "bob", "foo");
    hm_add(hm4, "alice", "bar");
    hm_add(hm4, "jane", "baz");

    hm_del(hm4, "jane");
    char* e = hm_get(hm4, "jane");
    assert(strcmp(e, "\0") == 0);

    // test deleting an item in the middle of the linked list.
    Node** hm5 = hm_create();
    hm_add(hm5, "bob", "abc");
    hm_add(hm5, "alice", "123");
    hm_add(hm5, "jane", "xyz");

    hm_del(hm5, "alice");
    char* f = hm_get(hm5, "alice");
    assert(strcmp(f, "\0") == 0);

    printf(
        "############################\n"
        "----- ALL TESTS PASSED -----\n"
        "############################\n"
    );
}
```
````

Comment: Note: I'm not sure my hash function is a great choice for quasi-evenly distributing items across the 'buckets'. Perhaps higher prime seed values could ameliorate that.

Comment: I will also note that my interface is missing a way to delete an entire hashmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`hashmap.c` in `hashmap.h`??**

Very unusual to `#include "hashmap.c"` in a header file.  Header files are expected to not generate code, just define and declare things.

Best to remove `#include "hashmap.c"`

**Strange string compare**

Simplify

```
// if (strcmp(node->value, "\0") == 0){
if (node->value[0] == 0) {

// strcpy(node->key, "\0");
    node->key[0] = 0;
```

**Use `const`**

When referenced data does not change, use `const`.

```
// void hm_add(Node** hmap, char key[], char value[]){
void hm_add(Node** hmap, const char key[], const char value[]) {
```

**Prevent buffer overflow**

`strcpy()` risks buffer overflow.  Consider protection.  Example:

```
// strcpy(node->value, value);
snprintf(node->value, sizeof node->value, "%s", value);
```

Of course if the string is too long, better code would detect that and complain.  Even better, save a copy of the string with `strdup()`.

**Bug: hash**

`modular_hash()` does not limit its return value to [0...BUCKETS).  I'd expect a mod:

```
size_t modular_hash(const char* string) {
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (char* character=string; *character != '\0'; character++) {
        hash += ((int)*character + PRIME_SEED_1) * PRIME_SEED_2; 
    }
    hash %= BUCKETS;  // add
    return hash;
}
```

**Weak hash**

Does not vary on order.

`modular_hash("abc")` == `modular_hash("bca")` == `modular_hash("cab")` == ...

**Tip: mod by prime**

Using `hash %= BUCKETS;` above, with `BUCKETS` as a prime or not,  makes little difference if the hash function was good.  Yet with a modest or weak hash, using a *prime* for `BUCKETS` improves the overall hash.  I recommend changing `BUCKETS` from 1000000 to a prime near that.

**Pointless cast**

Cast  `(int)*character` in `modular_hash(char* string)` serves no purpose.  If anything a cast to `unsigned` makes some sense.

**Good for only 1 map**

`hm_create(void)` uses `static Node* keys[BUCKETS] = {};` limiting us to 1 hash map.  Better to allocate to allow multiple instantiations of the hash map.

**Unneeded include**

`#include <stddef.h>` not needed in `hashmap.h`.

---

**Unneeded cast**

Casts does not improve safety - not needed to convert a `void *` to some object pointer..

```
// Node* node = (Node*)ptr; // safely typecast the pointer
Node* node = ptr;
```

**`"\0"`??**

Every place where `"\0"` (2 *null characters*, one explicit, one implied) is used can be replaced with `""`.

**Good test code**

**Return distinction**

`hm_get()` returns a pointer to `""` when none is found.  Yet if the item in the table was `""`, we do not know if the function succeeded or failed.  Instead, consider returning `NULL` on failure.

**Fixed hash size**

A more advanced hash table would adjust the hash table size as needed.

**Comments**

IHO, a satisfying amount of comments.